# Why can't I get the request attributes back in laravel controller contructor?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to get the authenticated user in the constuctor of my controller in laravel by doing `dd(auth()->user());` and it says null. I even added the user id into a request attribute in one of my middleware like so:

```
$request->attributes->add(['auth_user_id' => $user_id]);
```

Even if I do `dd($request->get('auth_user_id')` in my controller's construct method, I get null. But when I do the same thing in a test route, Both die dump statements work well and give me back the user or the user id, whichever I ask for.

Why am I not able to get these in the construct method of my controller tho? I am even able to get the same user id and auth user in my controller method to which the request goes to. Just not the construct method. What am I missing?

Comment: Controllers are instantiated before middleware was executed https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php#L50

Comment: Can you suggest a way around this tho?

Comment: Sure thing. Don't use it in the constructor. You don't need it there anyway.

Answer (score 1):

With Laravel 5.3, this change was introduced where middleware are initialized after the controller class is constructed. This means app-critical middleware like `Auth --specifically Auth::user()` are not available to the controller's `__construct()` method.

Please refer this documentation.
https://github.com/laravel/docs/blob/5.3/upgrade.md#session-in-the-constructor

## Edit

This way you can implement what you needed.

This will allow registering a closure middleware in the controller's constructor, so that any `auth/session` stuff can be called and set as properties on the controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        $this->user = $request->user();

        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

Refer this link by [Controller closure middleware - JosephSilber](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/15080)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because constructor method called when the object of class initialized and at that time you are not logged in and when you are not logged in you cannot get the **auth_user_id**.

But In case of normal method, they are called after constructor method, and you are logged in that's why you are able to get the **auth_user_id**